# Merge partial DB table into another DB table?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

1) I currently have my current database exported into an SQL file.

2) I also have a second SQL file that contains 80 exported rows from a table from a second database (same type of database as my current database, all data is consistent).

I'd like to essentially shove these 80 rows into a specific table in my current database, but I have no experience with this type of stuff and don't know what to do. I don't want to replace anything, just append.

I've already imported the complete database SQL file into a clean installation with phpMyAdmin, but I'm not sure what to do with this SQL file of 80 rows or how to put these 80 rows into the table of the same-name of the current database.

Is this something I can do purely from a GUI standpoint with phpMyAdmin?

Comment: phpMyAdmin has an import option allowing you to import SQL files by selecting the database and/or table and going to the import tab (this might vary across phpMyAdmin version). 

Does your second SQL file have an INSERT statement for these 80 exported rows, and is the table name the same as the name of the table you are trying to import to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's a GUI way for this, but you can easily issue

```
insert into TABLE1 select * from TABLE2
```

Provided TABLE1 is your current table and TABLE2 holds the 80 rows.

Afterwards you can delete the TABLE2.
You must be sure, however, that you have no issues with unique indexes.
Here's the docs for more options
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks like it would work. Only trouble I'm having is I don't know how to get my SQL file with the 80 rows into table form. I feel like I can't just import it because I only exported select rows, not an entire table, when creating the SQL file.

Comment: Nevermind, I was running into an issue I guess because I was importing a table with the same name as another table.

Basically renamed TABLE1, imported TABLE2 as a temporary TABLE1, ran your function, then deleted TABLE2 and renamed TABLE1 back to normal.

Amazingly it worked, thanks.